# Email filter in default admin users/people search form

Tags: 7, users, search, forms, emails

I would like an additional filter (email-text input) in the drupal7 default admin users/people search form. Is there any module as I can't find one for drupal7?
I found that another way is the use of views but I want the default search form with additional input filter.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: The `admin/people/people` user overview doesn't have a search form, only filters. I don't know about adding a search form to it (I would turn to Views), but the `search/user` page does search name and email fields, so that's at least something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [this module](https://drupal.org/project/admin_views) achieve what you need.